# Patterns emerging from striped yarns in knitting

Tags: visualization

There's an interactive tool on [this page](http://yarnsub.com/articles/techniques/taming-multicolored-yarns/) that shows what happens when you knit a symmetrical striped yarn back-and-forth at different stitch counts (you can drag the stitch counter and it changes the picture).

What body of maths covers this kind of thing?

[image]
[image]